# Python Selenium Error - Nothing happening when webdriver

Tags: selenium, screen-scraping

[image: Screenshot]

As the image shows. SublimeText3, I have installed the selenium package but it still won't work. Anyone could help me?

It suppose to open a browser but it did nothing.

Comment: Please include the details of the error and the code in your question rather than just having a link to an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you download and apply chromedriver or geckodriver (Firefox) to your project ?

Comment: You were right. I neglected this step. Thanks for your help I fixed the problem.

Comment: No problem, have fun with selenium :)